# make it simpler so it will be quicker

Tags: ruby

I am quite new and got an issue with an exercise.
I solved it, works, but it's too slow when it comes to check more numbers-maximum length aprox. = 1.000.000 .
How could it been written for a quicker solving?

```
def find_dups_miss(arr)
    ((arr.sort.first..arr.sort.last).to_a - arr.sort)  + [arr.select{|item| arr.count(item) > 1}.uniq.sort]
end
```

testing:

```
arr1 = [10,9,8,9,6,1,2,4,3,2,5,5,3]
    Test.assert_equals(find_dups_miss(arr1),[7, [2, 3, 5, 9]])
```

It needs to find the missing number and the duplicates.

the error message:
Why did my code time out?
Our servers are configured to only allow a certain amount of time for your code to execute. In rare cases the server may be taking on too much work and simply wasn't able to run your code efficiently enough. Most of the time though this issue is caused by inefficient algorithms. If you see this error multiple times you should try to optimize your code further.

Comment: Here's a couple of tips: you are sorting the array three times. What language construct do you know that lets you "save" the result of a computation and re-use it multiple times? But actually … do you need to sort the array to find the largest and smallest element? Can you think of a way by looking at every element only once instead of multiple times as `sort` does? (Oh, and once you have found it, I am going to tell you about `Enumerable#minmax` ;-) )

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad just because the code works, does not mean it is off-topic on SO.

Comment: to "save" i tried sort! , but it wasn't working.

i sorted so i can have a full length of the numbers, so i can get the missing one, because on the testing is arr1 = [10,9,8,9,6,1,2,4,3,2,5,5,3] from which i couldn't see another way of finding the missing number.

Comment: Questions should always begin with,a statement of the problem, something like the first paragraph of my answer. Also, I don't know exactly when you awarded the green checkmark (within an hour of posting the question, presumably), but there is no rush to do so. Early selections can discourage other answers and, if done soon after the minimum wait time, is seen by some as discourteous to those still preparing questions. Many here wait at least a couple of hours. I am not saying this because I have a dispute your choice, just because you seem to be new to SO.

Comment: "to "save" i tried sort!" – Have you been taught about "variables" yet?

Comment: Is there only ever 1 missing number or could there be multiple?  ie what should an input of `[12, 10, 9, 8, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 3]` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree this is better put on code review, but to answer your question there are better data structures for solving this problem, consider using as hash:

```
def find_dups_missing(arr)
  min, max = arr.min, arr.max
  hash = {}
  min.upto(max) { |i| hash[i] = :sentinel }
  arr.each { |el| hash[el] == :sentinel ? hash[el] = 1 : hash[el] += 1 }

  hash.select { |_, v| v == :sentinel }.keys << hash.select { |_, v| v != :sentinel && v > 1 }.keys
end
```

We loop through, build a hash where each key is a number from `min` to `max` and the value points to an object that is just a placeholder (I called it `sentinel`).

Next we loop through our array, we ask if the hash value is still in its placeholder position, if it is, set the value to `1` but if it's not, just increment.  This way, we keep track of when we see a value for the first time vs. subsequent times (ie dupes).

Then, after it's all said in done, we have a hash that looks like this:

```
{1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>2, 4=>1, 5=>2, 6=>1, 7=>:sentinel, 8=>1, 9=>2, 10=>1}
```

We know where the value is `> 1`, we have duplicates and we also know where the value still says `sentinel` we never saw it in our array, there's our gap(s).

All together, this method runs in `O(n)` time (on average) with `O(n)` space.

Comment: thank you, but it gives an issue Expected: [7, [2, 3, 5, 9]], instead got: [[7], [2, 3, 5, 9]]

Comment: and it worked. thank you. now I'm gonna do my research to understand all of your program

Answer (score 3):

We are given an array of integers, `arr` with the property that it contains every integer between `min_val` and `max_val` but one, where `min_val, max_val = arr.minmax`. We wish to determine the missing integer and also the duplicate values in `arr`.

```
require 'set'

def missing_and_dups(arr)
  smallest, largest = arr.minmax
  dups = Set.new
  all = arr.each_with_object(Set.new) { |n,all| dups << n if all.add?(n).nil? }
  [(smallest+largest)*(largest-smallest+1)/2 - all.sum, dups.to_a]
end

missing_and_dups [10,9,8,9,6,1,2,4,3,2,5,5,3]
  #=> [7, [9, 2, 5, 3]]
```

Note that [Set#add?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F) returns `nil` if the element being added is already in the set. Rather than finding the missing element `n` with

```
((smallest..largest).to_a - arr).first
```

I've made use of the fact that

```
all.sum + n = (smallest+largest)*(smallest+largest-1)/2
```

Comment: very clever Cary!  On a large input size, yours is performing the best

Comment: One assumption you're making here and to be fair the OP didn't qualify it differently is that you're only finding _one_ number that is missing.  I wonder if `[12, 10, 9, 8, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 3]`, should include 11 and 7?

Comment: @Anthony, I was working backwards. I wanted to use the expression for the sum of an arithmetic series so I had no choice but to assume exactly one value was missing. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is about as fast as I can get this problem for now

```
def find_dups_miss(arr)
  groups = arr.group_by(&:itself) 
  arr.minmax.reduce(:upto).to_a - groups.keys << groups.select {|_,v| v.size > 1}.keys.sort
end
```

Explanation based on posted `Array`

First we group the `Array` elements by themselves

```
{10=>[10], 9=>[9, 9], 8=>[8], 6=>[6], 1=>[1], 2=>[2, 2], 4=>[4], 3=>[3, 3], 5=>[5, 5]}
```

Then we create an `Enumerator` from the minimum and maximum (`arr.minmax.reduce(:upto)`) values from the `Array`, covert it to an `Array` (`to_a`) and subtract all the `keys` from the previous group grouping:

```
arr.minmax.reduce(:upto).to_a - groups.keys
#=> [7]
```

Then we collect of all the numbers that occurred more than once in the original `Array`: (I sorted them because the desired result was sorted)

```
groups.select {|_,v| v.size > 1}.keys.sort
#=> [2, 3, 5, 9]
```

and use `Array#<<` to push this `Array` back into the one we created in the previous step resulting in

```
#=> [7,[2, 3, 5, 9]]
```

If there is only ever 1 number missing then the following is slightly faster since it does not create an additional `Array` and short circuits on the first missing number:

```
def find_dups_miss(arr)
  groups = arr.group_by(&:itself) 
  [groups.select {|_,v| v.size > 1}.keys.sort].unshift(arr.minmax.reduce(:upto).find {|n| groups[n].nil?} )
end
```

Additionally for a very large `Array`:

```
groups.collect {|k,v| k if v.size > 1 }.compact.sort
```

appears to be slightly more efficient than

```
groups.select {|_,v| v.size > 1}.keys.sort
```